# localhost redirected you too many times ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using devise/Ruby on Rails and when I try to open my localhost I get the following infinite loop, and have no idea why since the only change I've made was creating seeds using the Faker gem, and creating a show view for when the user logs in.

At first I thought it was something wrong with my if/else statement in my controller, since when I reseed the data, there's no current_user signed in and it should take me to the new user registration path created through devise, but was lost as to why it repeats itself..

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is terminal:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-30 13:53:58 -0800
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"sign_in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

UsersController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!

  def show
    if current_user.present?
      @user = current_user
      @item = Item.new
      @items = @user.items
    else
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path
    end  
  end
end
```

Users#show

```
<h2> Your to-do list</h2>


  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class='items'>
      <%= render partial: "items/item", local: { item: @item} %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class='new-item'>
      <%= render partial: "items/form", local: { item: @item } %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  get 'welcome/about'

  root 'users#show'

  resources :users do
    resources :items, only: [:new, :create, :index]
  end


  devise_for :users
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was able to figure out the root issue, being order of placement of code in routes.rb.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `devise_for :users` in your routes.

Comment: sorry wasn't able to format it correctly! it's there however :(

Comment: Ah ok good :) just make sure it's not outside the first 'end'

Answer (score 0):

You have already permission denied for guest user I mean which user not signed in using devise this `before_action :authenticate_user!` this means user not accesing any action from `UsersController` which not signed in after that you have redeclared permission on `show` action `if current_user.present?` which is not actually needed then `show` action should something like this

```
@user = current_user
@item = Item.new
@items = @user.items
```

Remove the `if` `else` condition.

Hope to help

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

**users_controller.rb**

```
  before_action :logged_in?, only: :new

  def new
    @user = User.new
    render layout: "session"
  end
```

and

**application_controller.rb**

```
def logged_in?
    redirect_to users_new_url unless current_user.present?
end
```

When I was trying to redirect to the **'users/new'** page, the same error occurred.

This is just because I'm trying to redirect to the **'users/new'** page and **def logged_in?** is also redirecting to the same page.

Then I changed the **application_controller.rb** code like this:

```
def logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url unless current_user.blank?
end
```

**Error_Resolved.**